# What's between "children" and "olders"?

Tags: word-request

If **children** go to pediatrician and **olders** go to  geriatrician. what is the one between these two (children is called in English? I thought about 'adult' but I'm not sure since adult includes older.

> **Children** should go to pediatrician and **olders** should go to geriatrician and **(......?)** should go to GP.

Comment: "Olders"? Do you mean "elders"?

Comment: Most likely you're thinking of **seniors** not **olders**. If the prices of services vary by age, they are normally broken down into four categories: children, students, adults, and seniors. While *students* isn't only related to age, most people qualify it by saying things like "to qualify for student pricing you must be between the ages of X an Y." Typically, if somebody *has* specific age categories, then **adults** actually is the one you're looking for—because it will include only those people between a minimum and maximum age.

Comment: Children go to a pediatrician, seniors go to a geriatrician—and adults go to a general practitioner. (If such distinctions are to be made, because GPs can see people of any age.)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a word for adults that excludes the elderly? I can't really think of one. I mean, I suppose we have children, teenagers, young people, middle-aged people, and elderly people. We also call people 20 somethings, 30 somethings, and so on.

Specifically, in the context of your original question, none of those work very well, though. I suppose I might say something like the following:

> Children go to pediatricians. Adults go to general practitioners until they get old enough to consider switching to a geriatric physician.

I can't think of a single word that means "all adults except elderly ones," though.

On a side note, I believe a gerontologist is a scientist who studies aging, not a doctor.